# みんなで笑った　ー who made what laugh?

Tags: grammar, translation, meaning, particle-で

ok so, i'm reading デューク and there's a line that says

> その格好がモップに似ていると言って、みんなで笑った。

with my limited comprehension, i'm unsure of whether this means

- everybody laughed that he resembled a mop.
- i laughed when people said he looked like a mop.
- something else completely

i read [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/15486/how-do-i-express-this-made-me-laugh/15516#15516) which is what made me think my first translation was probably wrong, but i'm still quite unconfident on the matter...

Answer (score 1):

The more context the better (we don't even have a subject here), but I would understand it as: *everybody laughed*

The linked question is a bit different, it is about 笑わせる which is a causative form - it's about making (or letting) someone laugh (and I believe これ vs みんな can also make a difference).

Here, you can say で marks a way how the verb was performed and that is "as everyone".

It is similar to other constructs like 一人で (by myself, alone)、家族で (as a family), ...

Comment: You can also check https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/44711/9719  
It describes this expression from maybe? a different angle using formal sources, though I cannot think of a difference it would practically make. This answer is about how I understood it

Comment: See also: http://www.lit.kobe-u.ac.jp/linguistics/sells-postconf-ho.pdf

Comment: Thank you very much for the link. I'll give it a read, for now I'll keep hoping my answer is not wrong then : )

Comment: (if we assume the possibility of a hidden subject)

Comment: Well, I upvoted because I think your explanation ('everybody laughed') is the right way to understand it.  I don't think you can add a が-marked subject in addition to みんなで, though, so I think it might be best analyzed as what Martin calls a 'group subject'.  We could see if anyone else has an opinion about adding a が-phrase, though.  I'm just a learner, and my intuitive judgments aren't always right.